# Can we send data through any of the parameters in react-native-webview?

Tags: javascript, android, html, react-native-webview

Can we send data content in any of the parameters of react-native-webview?I have a web-view in which I would like to send a path. This path is to be sent to an external html file. Is there any way or any parameter in which I could give the path which would direct it to the html file stored in android-assets?

```jsx
<WebView 
  source={{htmlData}} 
  originWhitelist={["*"]} 
  domStorageEnabled={true} 
  startInLoadingState={true} 
  javaScriptEnabled={true} 
  scalesPageToFit={true} 
  allowFileAccess={true} 
  injectedJavaScript={injectedToHtml()} 
  ref={(ref)=> { this.webViewRef = ref }} 
  onMessage={this.onMessage} />
```

Comment: Did you google this issue? What was the result? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, you can [edit] your question and format it properly there